# Remove <> this from string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to do a basic string replace using a regex expression.But i want to only remove `<>` tags from string.
I have a string like this:

> < >< >Non-Fairtrade organized event-organized-Conferences, seminars.

Comment: `<>` or html tags?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I have string "< >< >Non-Fairtrade organized event-organized-Conferences" like this

Comment: You don't need a regex for static values. `str_replace('< >', '', $string)`, https://eval.in/656478. If there are multiple variations post those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to strip tags, you don't need a regex and you can leverage **[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)** built-in function.

Quoting the documentation:

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

Will print:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

Anyway, if you to use a regex, then you can use this regex:

```
<.*?>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/f3T9Ds/1)**

```
$re = '/<.*?>/';
$str = '< >< >Non-Fairtrade organized event-organized-Conferences, seminars.';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) here.

> **str_replace** - Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string
>
> mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject )

Try this:

```
$string = '< >< >Non-Fairtrade organized event-organized-Conferences, seminars.';

echo str_replace(array('<', '>'), '', $string); // Non-Fairtrade organized event-organized-Conferences, seminars.
```

Comment: This isn't strict to `< >` though. If the string had `When 5 < 4 don't turn the dial.` you'd lose the `<`.